# Strcmp doesn't work and I don't seem to understand why - transformation to ASCII code makes the program work as expected though

Tags: c++, for-loop, c-strings, strncmp, floppy

First of all, please don't critique the way the program is written, because this is what we study in my country.

I know it is a mixture of C and C++ and the things I use are outdated, but that's how the things are here.

So I have to make a program which gets as an input n words. Then I have to print the words that have the last one as a prefix.

e.g.

```
input: 
n=6 
raita grai raid raion straie rai
output:
raita raid raion
```

This is my program. It works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char a[100][100];
    bool ok=1;
    cin >> n;
    cin.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin.get(a[i], 100);
        cin.get();
    }
    int p = strlen(a[n - 1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < p; j++)
        {
            ok = 1;
            if ((unsigned int)a[i][j] != (unsigned int)a[n-1][j])
            {
                ok = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

But initially, it looked like this:

```
/* strstr example */
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char a[100][100];
    bool ok=1;
    cin >> n;
    cin.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin.get(a[i], 100);
        cin.get();
    }
    int p = strlen(a[n - 1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < p; j++)
        {
            ok = 1;
            if (strcmp(a[i][j], a[n-1][j]) != 0)
            {
                ok = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

and it throws some errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"   ConsoleApplication1 25  

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'int strcmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'const char *'    ConsoleApplication1     25
```

I cannot seem to understand why this happens. Can any of you help me understand? Also, should I be using conversion to (unsigned int) or just strcmp?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use C parts within C++ code it is still C++.

Comment: What do you mean by "transform to ASCII"?

Comment: You should not call `strcmp` on each single character of the string. It already compares strings after all.

Comment: @user3121023 I'm comparing each letter. a[i]'s first letter with a[n-1]'s first letter, and so on.

Comment: @Gerhardh well it seems more like C to me tbh. The only C++ thing I'm using is iostream with cin/cout. Excepting that, everything is C-style, that's what I tagged it as C. Also, I didn't know that I can't use strcmp to compare each character.

Comment: @JohnSmith Then `strcmp` is the wrong tool for the job, it compares strings not characters.

Comment: @john Yeah. I didn't know that I can't use it to compare characters. Thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `j` loop completely and use `if (strcmp(a[i], a[n-1]) != 0)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- the requirement here is to find strings for which the final string is a **prefix**. It's not searching for identical strings, so `strcmp` won't work.

Comment: @PeteBecker - `strncmp` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

`strcmp` used to compare `string` and `string`. But in your code, you compare `char` and `char` (`a[i][j]` and `a[n-1][j]`).

In your case, you can use `strncmp` that compares only the first (at most) n bytes (in your case, n is `strlen(a[n-1])`) of two strings:

```
int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
```

So, your program becomes as below:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        ok = 1;
        if (strncmp(a[i], a[n-1], p) != 0)
        {
            ok = 0;
        }
        if (ok == 1)
        {
            cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know strncmp existed.

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
if (strcmp(a[i][j], a[n-1][j]) != 0)
```

the both expressions `a[i][j]` and `a[n-1][j]` have the type char while the function `strcmp` expects two pointers to strings of the type `char *`.

So the compiler issues an error.

You could simplify your first program using the standard function `strncmp`. For example

```
size_t p = strlen(a[n - 1]);
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
{
    if ( strncmp( a[i], a[n-1], p ) == 0 ) cout << a[i] << " ";
}
```

Pay attention to that you should use the header `<cstring>` instead of the header `<string.h>`,

Comment: Even if your answer is a bit better, I've chosen the other one as the correct one because it was faster. Can you elaborate on using "cstring" instead of "string.h"? As far as I know, cstring should be avoided (because it's obsolete).

Comment: @JohnSmith It is a requirement of the C++ Standard.

Comment: @JohnSmith -- `<cstring>` puts the names of the C functions that are declared in `<string.h>` into the namespace `std::`. It is not obsolete, and there is no reason to avoid it. There were some folks early on who thought the the entire C library should be tolerated until it could be removed. That effort quickly failed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest change to the code in the question is to change the test from `if (strcmp(a[i][j], a[n-1][j]) != 0)` to `if (a[i][j] != a[n-1][j])`.